# how to change datetimepicker font color when disabled & enable?

Tags: c#, vb.net, fonts, colors, datetimepicker

How do I change the font color of DateTimePicker to white color when this control is Disabled and to black color when Enabled?

Thanks.
Yudha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most cases need to use `DateTimePicker.OnEnabledChanged` event handler. See to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onenabledchanged.aspx).
[**Here**](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/95cd45e9-270e-47c0-b3bc-c52acdf587af) is answer to your question: